# Nginx configuration to work with Node.js

Tags: node.js, nginx, ghost-blog

I know there are similar questions or walkthroughs here or in web although i am stuck on this.

**The background**

I am trying to set up a local virtual host ghost.local where there will be a ghost blog(which is on Node.js).  So i want, when i visit http://ghost.local on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine the Nginx would pass request to Node.js and i 'll be able to see my ghost blog.

**The problem**

I 've set up *hosts* file i 've set up nginx vhosts my ghost is running on Node.js. Although when i visit http://ghost.local i get

*503 Service Unavailable Failed to resolve the name of server ghost.local*

My hosts file:

```
 127.0.0.1  ghost.local
 127.0.0.1  localhost
```

My /etc/nginx/sites-available/ghost.local file:

```
 server {
     listen 80;
     server_name ghost.local;
     access_log /var/log/nginx/ghost.local.log;

     location / {        
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header HOST $http_host; 

         proxy_pass http://localhost:2368;
         proxy_redirect off;
    }
 }
```

The link in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ghost.local is set up right.

I didn't post anything from ghost or node.js because on http://localhost:2368 is up and running everything fine.

Any idea anyone? 
Thank you all in advance.

**EDIT**
As i mentioned in my comment the problem most probably was on my machine set up the above configuration worked in a new machine.

Comment: pls add the following line to your server block and post the output after making a request to http://ghost.local: `error_log /var/log/nginx/ghost.local.err.log debug;`

Comment: I set all up on another machine, exactly the same way and everything is fine  I am still not sure what was the problem. Some minor changes are, newer version of node.js newer version of npm. Although i think the problem was at the previous machine since after-post tests i realize the proxing was working correctly from http://localhost to http://localhost:2368 and the problem was with the vhosts of nginx. Really thank you although for your time.

Answer (score 0):

First off it seems like you installed the wrong version of nginx. Did you install it yourself, if so you should reinstall nginx with the latest version.

Secondly, I am confused if your website is on http://ghost.local?

because `server_name` is supposed to be the sub/domain for your website, her is an example:

```
server_name www.example.com example.com test.example.com;
```

Here is what a basic nginx configuration for a website at http://example.com

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host      $http_host;
                proxy_pass                 http://127.0.0.1:2368;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com;
        return 301 http://example.com/$request_uri;
}
```

Make sure you restart nginx afterwords.

```
service nginx restart
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer as i mentioned in my edit my problem solved. As for my server name yes i wanted my main website (ghost.local) to be passed by nginx to node.js.